# Are algebraically isomorphic $C^*$-algebras $*$-isomorphic?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If A and B are C^*-algebras that are algebraically isomorphic to each other, does 
this imply that they are *-isomorphic to each other?

Comment: Why the vote to close? If I recall correctly this is a non-obvious result of Gardner (Gardener?) -- the point is that the given isomorphism between A and B is not assumed to be a star-HM

Comment: Note to the OP: the title of your question seems to be asking something more general than what you actually ask in your question...

Comment: I only clicked because I thought the first word was "homophobic" and now I feel dumb

Comment: Since there has been no response: I have edited the title of the question to match the actual question that was asked. If you object to this, *please* leave a comment to explain what you actually meant to ask

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answering the question in the body of the original post, which seems to be more restricted than the implicit question in the title of the post....

The answer is YES. See

> L. Terrell Gardner, *On isomorphisms of $C^\ast$-algebras.*
>   Amer. J. Math. **87** (1965) 384–396.
>   [MathReview](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=179637)

Roughly speaking, the proof works by considering the ${\rm C}^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ as being represented on the GNS spaces $H_A$ and $H_B$ given by all pure states of $A$ and $B$ respectively, and then showing that an algebra isomorphism $A\to B$ can be extended to a spatial isomorphism ${\mathcal B}(H_A)\to {\mathcal B}(H_B)$.

Note that the original question was apparently raised by Sakai, a few years before Gardner's paper.